# Change motherboard and CPU drivers of Windows XP without booting

Tags: windows-xp, boot, drivers, motherboard

I have a very old pc running Windows XP that died. I took the hard drive and connected it to a new system which has new CPU and motherboard (ASUS P5K-VM).

When I switch on, Windows XP boot menu appears, but it fails to boot, both in safe mode and in normal mode, because the drivers installed are different.

After some research, I found that in Windows 7, [you can use dism tool](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-repair-windows-7-install-after-replacing-motherboard/) to specify additional drivers in recovery mode. But I couldn't find any such tool for Windows XP.

I can mount the HDD in other OS and can see the files and the /windows folder. Is there any way, by which I can change the motherboard driver without booting, so that I can fix this issue?

Comment: I know of no way to fix your problem in such a way that doesn't require the actual installation to already be working

Answer (score 1):

You can try running a Windows XP repair install using an XP install disc, which may or may not work.  Aside from that, about the only option I am aware of in these situations is to re-install Windows XP on top of your existing installation using an install disc.

If you don't have access to an install or recovery disc, since all official support for XP is about to end and you've replaced your CPU and motherboard, I'd recommend upgrading to Windows 7.

Comment: I already tried to do a repair-install, but it didn't recognize my old installation. The main reason why I don't want to do a fresh install, is because the old instance has some *emotional* value for me.

Answer (score 1):

**This MIGHT work**

**The process will take hours and hours are you ready?**

Connect a new hard drive to the motherboard.

Install Windows XP from scratch.

Update it to the same patch level as the old computer

Install drivers

copy and new files in the following folders to your old windows install

c:\windows\system32\drivers

c:\windows\inf

Now you need a copy of the c:\windows\system32\config\SYSTEM file from new install

You will probably have to boot from the CD and go into the recovery console to copy above files since it is always in use.

After every thing in one the USB stick

shutdown

connect the existing copy of windows

backup the c:\windows\system32\config\SYSTEM

copy all data off USB stick back to the corresponding location.

reboot and see what happens

Comment: I am going to try this right away.

Answer (score -1):

> After some research, I found that in Windows 7, you can use dism tool to specify additional drivers in recovery mode. But I couldn't find any such tool for Windows XP.

For future readers, Macrium's Reflect has a ReDeploy feature that may work.  But because of XP's age, you may have to contact the company to get an older, XP-compatible version.

I also had some luck with @cybernard's suggestion, but, instead, copying/pasting branches of the Windows registry (from a working installation) with the free tools that are out there (like Registry Editor PE).